# Как в Ansible через json_query получить элемент верхнего уровня?

Tags: python, json, запрос, ansible

Есть файл: https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/languages.json там есть `native: "Русский"`. Как мне получить `ru`? Не обязательно `json_query` - но и самописных модулей на питоне тоже не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был задан, чтобы заработало определение языка в [роли Ansible по установке firefox](https://github.com/don-rumata/ansible-role-install-firefox).

Решилось пока что [так](https://github.com/don-rumata/ansible-role-install-firefox/blob/master/files/get-system-language.ps1):

```
#!powershell
# https://serverfault.com/a/173689/315697
$native_lang = $(Get-UICulture | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName).split(' ')[0]

# Thanks https://github.com/RedMadness
$url = 'https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/languages.json'
$json = Invoke-WebRequest $url | ConvertFrom-Json
$firefox_lang = echo ($json.psobject.Properties | ? {$_.Value -match "$native_lang"}).Name

$firefox_lang
```

Работает на Windows, но для неё всё и затевалось (во всяком случае пока).